# Facebook LoginActivity is not shown properly

Tags: android, facebook

I have an application that uses Facebook login. I have the FacebookSDK and I use com.facebook.LoginActivity.

The problem is that on 10" tablets the activity is not shown properly when the softkeybord is shown. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (10.1) (OS 4.0.2).

This is what I see after clicking on one EditText in the Facebook LoginActivity:

[image]

In the manifest file I have:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Is anyone else having this problem too?
Is anyone using LoginActivity without having problems?

Is there anything else I need to do?

And why does not the Facebook activity take the full screen ?

Comment: I also tried with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and without specifying anything as required by the doc

Comment: File a bug here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Let me see... [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/LoginActivity), they say clearly: _"This Activity is a necessary part of the overall Facebook login process but is *NOT* meant to be used directly."_ and again _"Do *NOT* start this activity directly."_ Anyway, for some mysterious reason, you *need* to start this activity, and, as expected, things are not working properly. Is this correct? Well, I wish I could help, but I took a look at the activity and there is no edit text in its layout, just a progress bar. Which LoginActivity we're talking about?

Comment: I'm not opening the activity directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quick fix will require you to modify the SDK code.

Look in the WebDialog.java file, in the onCreate() method, after the super.onCreate() call, add this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

This will pan the soft keyboard over top of the dialog. If that's still not enough, then you might want to play around with the margins in the getMargins() method. In the worst case, you can just have getMargins return:

```
return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 1);
```

Comment: So you are assuming that the problem is in the sdk and not in the way I use it. Have you seen this problem before?

Comment: I'm not assuming, I'm saying there's a bug in the SDK. Source: I work on the SDK.

Comment: BTW, version 3.6 of the SDK addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world are you using com.facebook.LoginActivity? Just authenticate your session using a facebook Session and authenticate through SSO or if not available through the web.

### Update

Refer to this URL about SSO:

http://facebooksso.blogspot.com/2012/04/single-sign-on-facebook.html

Comment: THis is not a question, its providing a different way to achieve a login. Please read my full post before making such a conclusion. Read the update on the post for more info.

Comment: Sorry but I can't use that way of signing in. I have to keep using the LoginActivity...

Comment: Sounds like bad design to me.. but to each their own :)

Comment: The link you posted is old and is no longer the recommended method of achieving login via the SDK.