# Keyboard is overlapping facebook login screen

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK and using the Facebook Login Button. When I click to log in, a facebook pop-up shows. My problem is that when the screen is on landscape and I start typing the e-mail, the Keyboard overlaps the pop-up and I can't see what I'm typing, just show the header of the pop-up. When the screen is on portrait, the pop-up is normal and I can type with no problem.

Here is my login.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" ><FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:background="@drawable/background_land"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/acLogin_FrameLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
 </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way that I can still use Facebook Login Button and set the pop-up login frame to not become almost invisible?

Comment: This is a known bug, see the workaround I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364890/facebook-loginactivity-is-not-shown-properly

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the windowSoftInput mode on your activity. My guess is android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or "adjustPan". You can set it on the activity inside your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I tried something like this but still didn't work:         
`<activity android:name="com.example.goldfinger.Login_Fragment"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"android:label="@string/title_activity_login__fragment" ></activity><activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"     /><activity android:name="com.example.goldfinger.LoginUsingLoginFragmentActivity"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>`